# iOS Multiple Navigation Controllers with swipe menu

Tags: ios, xcode4, uistoryboardsegue, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I implemented a Facebook like swipe menu, but i have problems with the navigation.

I have 3 ViewControllers

- MainViewController, which contains the other two
- HomeViewController, which is the 'Home page' of my application
- SwipeMenuViewController, which contains buttons for the further navigaiton

Now i want to perform a segue from the HomeViewController to the Second page.
I placed a button at the HomeViewController and cmd + dragged it to the second page, Action segue: Push.

When i run the application, i get the next error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason:
'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by
an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

So basically I want to create the exact same navigation what the facebook uses, menu button at the main page else back button at the top left corner.

Any idea would be appreciated!

[image: StoryBoard]

[image: Facebook like swipe menu]

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but you could think about using https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck , it does exactly what you want but it's made very good and straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a container view controller. Instead of having the menu leave the current view controller and go to a different one, have the menu come up as a child view controller in a pre-defined view on the original view controller.

This has some benefits like:

1. Custom animations of the menu appearing/disappearing
2. Partial screen menus which leave some of the original screen visible (makes users feel like it's a menu and they are still at the same place)

When the user triggers the menu (swipe/tap/etc) you would add the menu "child" view controller to the (offscreen) view, then animate the view to visible location (which could be as simple as changing the frame.origin.x). When dismissed just reverse the process.